# Vim Taglist Yellow Highlight on Tags

Tags: vim, tags, vim-plugin, taglist

I have just now installed tag list plugin. It is working fine except when, from the tag list window, I try to press Enter then the corresponding tag becomes yellow colored and hence I could not see anymore what I just searched for. How to change the color to more visible one?

Also the searched Tag position is not fixed, it does not come in alignment with the tag in tag list window, is there any way to solve this?

The line which I am actually trying to copy/paste in my `.vimrc` is

```
highlight Search        ctermfg=red ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold,underline
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question about alignment, TagList is AFAIK not supposed to do that so there's nothing to "solve". If you want that feature, send a feature request to the author.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find the Yellow color, by typing `:highlight`. It lists all the different highlight groups (Comments, Function, Search,..), and the associated color.

The color of the different highlight groups are defined in the `colorscheme`.

You can find the current colorscheme in use by typing `:colorscheme`.

Then you have different options.

1. You can edit the colorscheme to modify the Yellow to something more readable that is stored in `$HOME/.vim/colors` (or `$VIMRUNTIME/.vim/colors` for system wide modification).
2. You can decide to use a completely different colorscheme by adding in your .vimrc a line, with `colorscheme new_theme`.
3. You can redefine the value of the single highlight group you want to change in your `.vimrc`

Assuming you want to modify the 'Search' group, you have to clear it first. For example, in your `.vimrc`:

```
 colorscheme  delek
 highlight Search    NONE
 highlight Search    gui=none      guifg=#544060 guibg=#f0c0ff ctermbg=1
```

You can find more information by using Vim built-in help.
`:help highlight`
`:help colorscheme`

Comment: I have a vimrc file in which highlight Search was already there with some default configuration which i want to change to something else (may be blue bg and red fg and bold text --> whenever i search for a pattern then search pattern should appear in this form ). I did that but no change has happened.
Actually I donot want to use new color scheme.
Also i dont have any .vim/colors directory.

Comment: And also one more thing is that when i m typing :colorscheme inside vim its saying "cannot find color scheme . "

Comment: See I modified it by going to vimrc file and just replacing the already present line there by my line after that i saved the file closed the putty and started it again but couldn`t see any change.

Comment: colorscheme delek                                        "searchpattern
highlight Search        ctermfg=red ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold,underline

Comment: Above two lines are there in my vimrc file ..i dont know whether i am using the delek colorscheme or not

Comment: No its not commented.

Comment: I have finally found the solution. If you want to modify a highligth group after it has been initialized once, you have to clear it first with `hi Search NONE`. I have tried on my install, and it works in runtime.

Comment: I have added highlight Search NONE and in the next line highlight Search ctermfg=red ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold,underline  is there but i  m still not able to do so . Do

Comment: Sorry I am out of ideas.